# Would a Muslim marriage from Indonesia be recognized for a French spouse visa application?

Tags: france, marriage, indonesia

I and my fiancee will get married in Indonesia. I am Mauritian and she is Indonesian and we are both of the same religion. I live in France and after the marriage, she will have to apply for French Visa from Embassy of France in Indonesia.

Our marriage, both the legal and religious will be performed at the same place. Then we will be given the marriage certificate. Using this marriage certificate, will we able to use it directly at the french embassy ?

Comment: [TLS](https://fr.tlscontact.com/id/JKT/page.php?pid=family_reunion_spouse_more90) says they need the original, a copy, and a translation among other documents.